# Simple Javascript with classnames

Tags: javascript, html, class, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to have the script ask the user for an HTML class name and a color name, and then sets the color of all the elements of that HTML class to the given color.

I set the html to have `class = wish` and there is a `li` element with `class = class2`.  The sytax is correct for that.  I just don't know what to do for it.  I have been just testing alot with the `document.getElementsByClassName()` feature and it hasn't worked well for me.

```
/*var classask=window.prompt("which class?");
var nodes = getElementsByClassName(classask);
document.writeln(nodes);*/

var styx=window.prompt("pick a classes name so for usage");
var nodes =document.getElementsByClassName(styx);
document.write(nodes);
nodes.style.color=red;
//document.write(document.getElementsByClassName(styx));
//document.writeln(x);
//document.write(document.getElementByClass(styx));
HTMLElement.Object.className=styx;
document.writeln(styx);

//var newcolor=window.prompt("pick a new color for usage");
//var nodes=(document.getElementByClass(classname));
//HTMLElementObject.className=styx;
//nodes.style.color=newcolor;
```

The code basically is alot of testing done by myself, I am just not sure how to get it to work. I either get it where it doesn't do anything or it just says `[object HTMLCollection]`  always no matter what i put in.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `nodeList`.  This is a list of nodes.  To operate on all the nodes in the `nodeList`, you must loop over the `nodeList` and apply your change to each item in the `nodeList` like this:

```
var newcolor = window.prompt("pick a new color for usage");
if (newcolor !== null) {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.color = newcolor;
    }
}
```

FYI, you also had `getElementByClass` when it should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

A *NodeList* doesn't have a `style` property. You have to loop over the *HTMLElementNodes* in the *NodeList* (it is very much like an array) and access the `style` property of each one in turn.